# How to use comaprison operators in where clause with select statement?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am currently working on a query on HIVE and using SQL Workbench. I want to get data from 2 tables on a monthly basis. For referencing the dates I am using another table that has two columns: `start_Date` and `end_date`. `start_Date` contains *month* and *starting date*, i.e. 01/01/2018. Similarly `end_date` contains *month* and *end date*, i.e. 31/01/2018.

The query goes something like:

```
select *
from table1 a join
     table2 b
     on a.pkey = b.pkey
where effective_date >= (select start_Date
                         from date_table
                         where year(start_date) = year(current_date) and month(start_date) = month(current_date)
                        );
```

but obviously it is not working.

Could someone please give me a correct solution for this problem?

Let me know if there are any doubts.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: hi, sample data is as follows   
tarrif_name  tarrif_start_date  tarrif_end_date
plan1         09/08/2018          31/09/2019
plan2         01/09/2013          31/02/9999
plan3         01/01/2012          01/09/2018
plan4         01/01/2014          31/08/2016   
I want the plans active for the particular month and the first and last dates of the months are in another table as mentioned in the problem.

Comment: What's the error message? Is the result of your nested query a single value?

Comment: yes the result for the nested query is a single date value which will have the date for eg. as 01/01/2018 starting of the month. Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: What's the error message? are you getting bad results or the query is failing?

Comment: error message is syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something like this can help you:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b
ON a.pkey = b.pkey
JOIN (SELECT start_Date
      FROM date_table
      WHERE year(start_date) = year(current_date)
      AND month(start_date) = month(current_date)
      ) dt
ON a.effective_date >= dt.start_date ;
```

I haven't tested the code since you haven't published sample data, but I hope it helps.